# Sending Push Notifications Within Journeys Triggered By An API Event Without DeviceID

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, mobilepush, mobileconnect, push-notification

I have the following Use Case:

- Journey is triggered from an API Event, It has PUSH Notification messages present.
- This Event does not have the Device ID which is used to send Push Notification to the Users
- Device IDs are present but in a separate table(Mobile Push)

The Question is:

**If API event is an entry source in the Journey for Push Notification Messages, but Device Id is present in a separate table, what is the best way to achieve the successful run of the Journey with each user receiving those Push Notifications**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the contact in your API event is already tied to a device ID in the Mobile Push channel, journey builder can send the Push Notification message to that contact without needing the Device ID value in the API send.

Normally, when people register in the app and the SDK registers that device into Mobile Push, it involves to the App side so no further action needed if it does properly.

In case, these contacts haven't been added to Mobile Push channel yet, you would need to import them first. You can refer to this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_import_contacts_best_practices.htm&type=5) to be aware the best practices for importing contacts into Mobile Push.

Also, in this article [Import Contacts into MobilePush](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_import_contacts_to_a_standard_list_or_into_all_contacts.htm&type=5), they also give step by step how to manual import contacts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go ahead and try this out and approve the answer post successfully achieving the goal!